# using printed value as input value in Python

Tags: python

Can somebody help me in my problem,please.

I am writting small script that reads user home directory,append name of folder and using file from that folder

```
import os
i=os.path.expanduser('~')
print ('{}\.myfolder'.format (i))
```

after that

```
myFile= ?????here must be resul of printing 
winsound.PlaySound(myFile,winsound.SND_NOSTOP)
```

Comment: Is _that_ the question?

Comment: Are you just looking for `'{}\.myfolder'.format (i)`?

Comment: Why can't you do: `myFile = '{}\.myfolder'.format(i);print(myFile);winsound.PlaySound(myFile, ...)`?

Comment: 1) You're confusing *printing* a variable with *assigning* it. You want to create a variable myFile. 2) A path is not a file, it's a directory. You can't play a directory. *myFile* needs a filename at the end of the path.

Comment: 3) You apparently want to find (say) all .mp3 files in a given directory, there are a ton of answers on SO on how to do that: see ["Find all files in directory with extension .txt with python"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-with-python) or other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually format the path, use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
>>> import os
>>> path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.myfolder') # save the value
>>> print(path)                                               # print it
C:\Users\falsetru\.myfolder
```

Comment: Thank you for help.
os.path.join is exactly what i was looking for
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. A path is not a file, it's a directory. You can't play a directory! *myFile* needs a filename at the end of the path. **You apparently want to find (say) all .mp3 files in a given directory**, there are a ton of answers on SO on how to do that: see ["Find all files in directory with extension .txt with python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-directory-with-extension-txt-with-python)
2. You're confusing *printing* a variable with *assigning* it. You want to create a variable `myFile = os.path.join(...whatever...)`